# Is there any way to switch off e-mail notifications in CiviCase?

Tags: email, civicase

It seems that CiviCase sends out e-mail notifications for any change that is done in case activities. Is there a way to switch off these automatic e-mail notifications? (manual e-mail messages should still be possible, though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can only switch off for email notifications for all activity mails, not specifically for case activities only.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Just one question for clarification: 
So you would solve this by by deactivating all outbound e-mails (or diverting them to a database) Or is there a specific setting for activity e-mails only?

Comment: I would not solve this by de-activating all outbound e-mails, I would untick the box at Adminster>Customize Data and Screens>Display Preferences (Notify Activity Assignees). I would assume this works for case activities too, but test!

Comment: Great! This seems to be it - well hidden in the admin menu... ;-) You can even exclude certain (case) activity types for notifications. Testing is essential in anything related to CiviCase anyway...